# How to annotate fields created by greendao with ToMany relationship

Tags: java, android, simple-framework, greendao

I am currently using a fork of greenDAO by Path that enables annotation of the Class, fields, methods, etc. generated by greenDAO.

However, when a create a field which has a ToMany relationship with another Class, I cannot seem to annotate is anymore. Is there a work around for this?

I am using the annotations for XML bindings using simple XML.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your generated class, override setChannels method and put your annotation there. inside that custom method, you can set channels manually.

don't forget to keep it inside KEEP sections ( if u don't have them, add schema.enableKeepSectionsByDefault(); to your generator).

Comment: Can you please provide an example?